# Realizar mutate em colunas simultaneamente

Tags: r, dplyr

Olá,

Tenho um dataframe em que quero aplicar a mesma função em diversas colunas ao mesmo tempo. Tentei usar o `dplyr::mutate_at` mas acho que não entendi a lógica dessa operação.

Primeiro o que eu consigo fazer:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:3), col2= c(4:6), col3 = c(7:9))

percentualize <- function(x){

    x <- paste0(x, "%")


}

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(col1 = percentualize(col1),
         col2 = percentualize(col2),
         col3 = percentualize(col3))
```

Como eu poderia operar nessas três colunas ao mesmo tempo sem precisar ficar repetindo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains('col')), .funs = funs(. = percentualize))

  col1 col2 col3 col1_. col2_. col3_.
1    1    4    7     1%     4%     7%
2    2    5    8     2%     5%     8%
3    3    6    9     3%     6%     9%
```

**Edição**

Se as variáveis possuem algo em comum, poderia utilizar esta característica para chamá-las de uma so vez. Considere os novos nomes abaixo:

```
df %>%
  mutate(coluna = percentualize(col1),
         variavel = percentualize(col2),
         lambda = percentualize(col3))
```

Como todas as variáveis possuem a letra `l` em comum, você pode fazer isso:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains('l')), .funs = list(. = percentualize))
```

Que daria o mesmo resultado:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col1_. col2_. col3_.
1    1    4    7     1%     4%     7%
2    2    5    8     2%     5%     8%
3    3    6    9     3%     6%     9%
```

As variáveis podem não ter nomes em comum, muitas vezes. Mas, suas classes podem apresentar semelhança. Assim, podes fazer uma análise pela classe do objeto, não pelos seus nomes. Suponha que suas variáveis sejam de classe `numeric`. Com `mutate_if` você faz isso:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, .funs = funs(. = percentualize))

  col1 col2 col3 col1_. col2_. col3_.
1    1    4    7     1%     4%     7%
2    2    5    8     2%     5%     8%
3    3    6    9     3%     6%     9%
```

Tudo o que for de classe `numeric` será considerada na análise.

Comment: Entendi, mas se as variáveis tivessem nomes diferentes, por exemplo "variavel" e "coluna" eu poderia fazer ```mutate_at(.vars = vars(variavel,coluna) , ...) ?```

Comment: Poderia. Por exemplo, se elas tivessem um padrão em comum (letra em comum), poderia usar `regex` pra identificar as variáveis.

Comment: Vou editar com um exemplo.

Comment: Teria que ser `vars("variavel", "coluna")`.

Comment: Ou isso que o @Rui propos.

Comment: @JessicaVoigt Ou `vars(col1:col3)` ou com números de colunas `vars(1:3)`.

Comment: Obrigada gente!

Comment: O `mutate_if` merecia mais um voto, mas não posso...